# Create Postgres User with admin rights just for one database

Tags: postgresql

How can I create a postgres user who has admin access only to one database but cannot inspect or interfere with other databases in the postgres instance? The use case is I'm creating a multitenant application

- where each tenant gets his own database in the postgresql instance and can create schemas, tables etc and
- perhaps use a few pg_tables to inspect his own database but not others.
- cannot change the name of the database as it's controlled by me

EDIT: Added more constraints

Comment: You could make that user the owner of that database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks! I forgot to mention, that user should not be able to change the database name as that is controlled by my application. Can he change the database name if I make him the owner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fairly trivial:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb;
GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE newdb TO newdba;
```

Add `pg_hba.conf` entries to allow `newdba` to connect to `newdb` only.